# deleting records from tables with constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got two tables (PreOrder, PreOrderDetails) where I want to delete records from. The tables have the classic relation where the foreign key of the details table refers to the primary key in the preorders table. PreOrder has ~16 million records and details ~60 million.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PreOrder](
    [PreOrderId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    -- more columns
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PreOrder] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [PreOrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PreOrder]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PreOrder_PreOrder] FOREIGN KEY([PreOrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PreOrder] ([PreOrderId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PreOrder] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PreOrder_PreOrder]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PreOrderDetail](
    [PreOrderDetailId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PreOrderId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    more columns
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PreOrderDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PreOrderDetailId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PreOrderDetail]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_PreOrderDetail_PreOrder] FOREIGN KEY([PreOrderId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[PreOrder] ([PreOrderId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PreOrderDetail] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PreOrderDetail_PreOrder]
GO
```

deleting 5 records from preorder takes 90 seconds which is too slow. I'm guessing it's because of the constraint where every time one preorderid is to be deleted it is checked against the full preorderdetails table.
Is that assumption correct?

What can I do to make this faster? Right now records are inserted faster than they can be deleted.

Comment: Based on the above script a DELETE against PreOrder would fail if there were any PreOrderDetail rows. How is the delete being done? Cascading RI, trigger?

Comment: 1) the foreign key `FK_PreOrder_PreOrder` on `PreOrder` doesn't make sense. it references itself. 2) You should have an index on `PreOrderDetail` for the `PreOrderId` column. Do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes no index on [PreOrderDetail].[PreOrderId] is going to be nice for inserts.
But it is not going to be good for selects and deletes based on the column.
You need an index on [PreOrderDetail].[PreOrderId]

And using uniqueidentifier for PK or index is not efficient they fragment rapidly.